# How to find list which items are not in output list and add list to output list?

Tags: python, list, matching

I have a list with id's called `total_list`. I want to add the list in `total_list` to an `accepted_list` if *none* of the ids are found in the `accepted_list`. Here is a data set and the code I used. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

> **Sample of total_list** =
>   [[u'19'], [u'34', u'36'], [u'34', u'36'], [u'50', u'51'], [u'46', u'47'], [u'48', u'49'], [u'38', u'39', u'40'], [u'41', u'42', u'44'], [u'46', u'47', u'48'], [u'47', u'48', u'49'], [u'37', u'50', u'51'], [u'294', u'295', u'296'], [u'296', u'297', u'298'], [u'37', u'38', u'51'], [u'41', u'42', u'43', u'44'], [u'37', u'38', u'39', u'40'], [u'294', u'295', u'296', u'297'], [u'40', u'41', u'43', u'44'], [u'295', u'296', u'297', u'298'], [u'784', u'785', u'786', u'793'], [u'26', u'787', u'788', u'789', u'808'], [u'38', u'39', u'40', u'41', u'43'], [u'40', u'41', u'42', u'43', u'44'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782'], [u'294', u'295', u'296', u'297', u'298'], [u'783', u'784', u'785', u'786', u'791', u'792'], [u'794', u'795', u'796', u'798', u'799', u'800'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'783'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'787', u'788'], [u'783', u'784', u'785', u'786', u'791', u'792', u'793'], [u'26', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'787', u'788', u'789'], [u'792', u'793', u'794', u'795', u'796', u'798', u'799'], [u'793', u'794', u'795', u'796', u'798', u'799', u'800'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'816', u'817'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'26', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'787', u'788', u'789', u'790'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'783', u'787', u'788', u'789'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'783', u'787', u'788', u'789'], [u'779', u'780', u'781', u'783', u'784', u'785', u'789', u'790', u'791'], [u'783', u'788', u'789', u'790', u'791', u'792', u'797', u'804', u'805'], [u'26', u'780', u'781', u'783', u'787', u'788', u'789', u'790', u'804'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'26', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'808', u'809', u'810', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'795', u'796', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'811'], [u'785', u'786', u'791', u'792', u'793', u'794', u'795', u'797', u'798', u'799'], [u'801', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'817', u'818'], [u'801', u'802', u'803', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815'], [u'784', u'785', u'790', u'791', u'792', u'793', u'794', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'803', u'804'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'808', u'809', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'792', u'793', u'794', u'795', u'796', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803'], [u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'806', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813'], [u'789', u'790', u'791', u'792', u'797', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'810', u'811'], [u'783', u'784', u'785', u'790', u'791', u'792', u'793', u'797', u'798', u'803', u'804', u'805'], [u'790', u'791', u'797', u'798', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811'], [u'797', u'798', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813'], [u'24', u'25', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'810', u'811', u'812'], [u'805', u'806', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'797', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814'], [u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'791', u'792', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'811', u'812'], [u'791', u'792', u'793', u'794', u'795', u'796', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'805', u'806'], [u'790', u'791', u'792', u'793', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'811'], [u'801', u'802', u'804', u'805', u'806', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'817', u'818']]

So when I go through my `total_list` the first item is 19, **which is not found in a list** in my **accepted_list(empty)**. As soon as it find an item in a list in `total_list`, which is in a list of my `accepted_list`, it won't add it to `accepted_list`.

```
accept_intersect = []
inaccept = False

for i in totallist:
    if not accept_intersect:
        accept_intersect.append(i)
        continue
    for p in i:
        for a in accept_intersect:
            if p in a:
                inaccept = True
                break
    if inaccept is False:
        accept_intersect.append(i)
    elif inaccept is True:
        pass

for a in accept_intersect:'
    print a
```

Comment: what's the point of `'` after `for a in accept_intersect:`? It should be removed, I guess

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah the `'` is a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not go with dict as a set is the native implementationfor any of the two use cases:

1) flatten on output

2) accept two-level output

The following answer is providing both possibilities (as it is not clear to me, which one is requested in the question):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

total_list = [['19'], ['34', '36'], ['34', '36'], ['50', '51']]

accept_intersect = []
seen = set()

for item_seq in total_list:
    for item in item_seq:
        hashable_item = tuple(item)
        if hashable_item not in seen:
            accept_intersect.append(item)
            seen.add(hashable_item)

print(accept_intersect)

accept_intersect = []
seen = set()

for item_seq in total_list:
    hashable_item = tuple(item_seq)
    if hashable_item not in seen:
        accept_intersect.append(item_seq)
        seen.add(hashable_item)

print(accept_intersect)
```

That yields on my machine when run:

```
['19', '34', '36', '50', '51']
[['19'], ['34', '36'], ['50', '51']]
```

So the main point that needs specification is if you want variant 1) the flattening, than you input is automatically hashable, thus fits in dicts and sets as key, so also both other proposed answers (to date) work. But if you want to accept lists as entries and want to filter out duplicates of lists and leve those unique intact (i.e. variant 2) without flattening, than the above trick of mapping the lists into a tuple before checking unqiueness is the way to go.

I left the tuple() call inside the flattening variant (the first loop) as this may be more robust and keeps the focus on the algorithm more clear (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably quicker to use a dictionary to store if you have seen an id or not.

```
accept_intersect=[]
seen = {}

for item in totallist:
    for sub_item in item:
        if sub_item not in seen:
            accept_intersect.append(sub_item)
            seen[sub_item] = True;

print accept_intersect
```

**EDIT, UPDATED ON REQUEST**

```
accept_intersect=[]
seen = {}

for item in totallist: 

    # Track if a subitem has been seen
    seen_flag = False

    for sub_item in item:

        # If it has been seen before
        # stop looking in this list
        if sub_item in seen:
            seen_flag = True
            break

        # Add seen item
        seen[sub_item] = True

    # If a subitem was seen, skip and continue
    # with the next loop.
    if seen_flag == True:
        continue
    
    # Only append if no items were seen before.
    accept_intersect.append(item)

#totallist = [['19'], ['19', '22']]
#accept_intersect -> [['19']]

#totallist = [['19'], ['19', '22'], ['43'], ['44', '45'], ['65', '19']]
#accept_intersect -> [['19'], ['43'], ['44', '45']]
```

Where you want to sort by highest to lowest doesn't concern this solution. When you construct your total_list input, just arrange it how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How do you get the list in total_list added? Like instead of appending sub_item you append the list of that sub item to accept_intersect? I want to use this in a next step

Comment: So you want to append the list of the sub item only if NO subitem is already in accept_intersect? If  `total_list = [['19'], ['19', '22']]`, what do you want accept_list to be? Is accept_list equal to `[ ['19'] ]` or is it `[ ['19'],['22'] ]`

Comment: Yeah, so the answer should be `accepted_list = [[19]]` .Now that I think about it, I should sort my total_list from highest to lowest, so ['19','22'] would come first and be added to accept_list.

Comment: I am not sure this works correctly in that case - please cf. my answer with two variants. Note: Keys for sets and dicts must be **hashable** in Python and `['19','22']` clearly is not ;-) without transforming it into a tuple (eg.) as I suggest.

Comment: Thanks. I've just had a look at it and it makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

Same in almost one-liner (with a different check algorithm and a small trick in the list comprehension):

```
ch_l=[]
out_l=[]
out_l=[x for x in total_list if any(y not in ch_l for y in x) and [ch_l.append(z) for z in x if x]]
```

Output:

> > > out_l=
> > >       [[u'19'], [u'34', u'36'], [u'50', u'51'], [u'46', u'47'], [u'48', u'49'], [u'38', u'39', u'40'], [u'41', u'42', u'44'], [u'37', u'50', u'51'], [u'294', u'295', u'296'], [u'296', u'297', u'298'], [u'41', u'42', u'43', u'44'], [u'784', u'785', u'786', u'793'], [u'26', u'787', u'788', u'789', u'808'], [u'778', u'779', u'780', u'781', u'782'], [u'783', u'784', u'785', u'786', u'791', u'792'], [u'794', u'795', u'796', u'798', u'799', u'800'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'816', u'817'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'26', u'780', u'781', u'782', u'787', u'788', u'789', u'790'], [u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817'], [u'783', u'788', u'789', u'790', u'791', u'792', u'797', u'804', u'805'], [u'26', u'808', u'809', u'810', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'808', u'809', u'810', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'816', u'817', u'818'], [u'795', u'796', u'797', u'798', u'799', u'800', u'801', u'802', u'803', u'811'], [u'801', u'806', u'809', u'810', u'811', u'812', u'813', u'814', u'815', u'817', u'818']]

I am still not completely sure if it is the algorithm requested by OP but the test output is ok and the code looks quite nice.

It also should be faster (I hope).